# vb.net focus listener ?

Tags: vb.net, textbox

So,i'm creating rows of textboxes programmatically.What i want to do is call a method whenever the user focuses the last row of textboxes so i can create another row below it.
In java i would just add a focus listener.
How can i achieve this in vb.net ?
I know about Me.ActiveControl and .focused but they won't listen for focus,they will just check for it when i call them,right ? How can i always listen for focus on all the textboxes i programmatically create ?
Thanks and have a nice day !

Answer (score 3):

Just use the [Enter event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.enter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the TextBox.  It fires when the text box gets the focus.

Do avoid creating rows of text boxes, that's *very* inefficient.  The proper control is a DataGridView, it already adds an extra row automatically.

Comment: +1 for the DGV control. Not only that but just to add - you can also, of course, bind a datasource to it and do some funky stuff to cells visually and otherwise too.

Comment: Also [GotFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.gotfocus(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: No, don't use GotFocus.  It is a low-level event that's affected too much by validation, which cancels focusing changes.  Leave is the correct one in almost any case, it is here.